# I want to multiple data tooltip with ChartJs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to when i hover the point, it will be show multiple tooltip as like down side image..

Im showing my code in down side too.

[I want to as like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFfeT.png)

[My code seems like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DICrA.png)

```
    <div class="col-sm-6"> <!-- My Html Code -->
        <h4 class="heading">Aylık Tıklanma ve Görüntülenme</h4>
        <canvas id="myLineChart" width="300" height="250"></canvas>
    </div> <!-- My Html Code -->


<div class="">  <!-- My JS-Php Code -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myLineChart');
        new Chart(canvas, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
        labels: ["<?php echo ayGetir("-11"); ?>","<?php echo ayGetir("-10"); ?>","<?php echo ayGetir("-9"); ?>","<?php echo ayGetir("-8"); ?>","<?php echo ayGetir("-7"); ?>","<?php echo ayGetir("-6"); ?>","<?php echo ayGetir("-5"); ?>","<?php echo ayGetir("-4"); ?>","<?php echo ayGetir("-3"); ?>","<?php echo ayGetir("-2"); ?>","<?php echo ayGetir("-1"); ?>","<?php echo ayGetir("now"); ?>"],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Tıklanma',
          yAxisID: 'A',
          data: ["<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-11")); ?>","<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-10")); ?>","<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-9")); ?>","<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-8")); ?>","<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-7")); ?>","<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-6")); ?>","<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-5")); ?>","<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-4")); ?>","<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-3")); ?>","<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-2")); ?>","<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-1")); ?>","<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("now")); ?>"],
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,0,0.2)",
          pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
          pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
        pointRadius: 4,


          }, {
          label: 'Görüntülenme',
          yAxisID: 'B',
          data: ["<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-11")); ?>","<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-10")); ?>","<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-9")); ?>","<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-8")); ?>","<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-7")); ?>","<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-6")); ?>","<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-5")); ?>","<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-4")); ?>","<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-3")); ?>","<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-2")); ?>","<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-1")); ?>","<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("now")); ?>"],
          backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,0,0.4)",
          pointRadius: 4,
          pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
          pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",

        }]
        },
            options: {
                scales: {
                  yAxes: [{
                    id: 'A',
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'left',
                  }, {
                    id: 'B',
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'right'
                  }]
                }
            }
        });
        </script>

    </div><!-- My JS-Php Code -->
```

But i want as like first image because my other point doesn't show.( It is staying behind )

I need your help if u know how to do this. Thanks for helps guys..

Comment: you should add your html code in the question, very few people(may be no one) like to see code as an image

Comment: I am doing, thanks for advice. @Deep

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

The solution is here;

```
<div class="">  <!-- line chart -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myLineChart');
        new Chart(canvas, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
        labels: ["<?php echo ayGetir("-11"); ?>","<?php echo ayGetir("-10"); ?>","<?php echo ayGetir("-9"); ?>","<?php echo ayGetir("-8"); ?>","<?php echo ayGetir("-7"); ?>","<?php echo ayGetir("-6"); ?>","<?php echo ayGetir("-5"); ?>","<?php echo ayGetir("-4"); ?>","<?php echo ayGetir("-3"); ?>","<?php echo ayGetir("-2"); ?>","<?php echo ayGetir("-1"); ?>","<?php echo ayGetir("now"); ?>"],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Tıklanma',
          yAxisID: 'A',
          data: ["<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-11")); ?>","<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-10")); ?>","<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-9")); ?>","<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-8")); ?>","<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-7")); ?>","<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-6")); ?>","<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-5")); ?>","<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-4")); ?>","<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-3")); ?>","<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-2")); ?>","<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-1")); ?>","<?php echo clickGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("now")); ?>"],
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,0,0.2)",
          pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
          //pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
          pointRadius: 4,
          fill: false
        },
        {
          label: 'Görüntülenme',
          yAxisID: 'B',
          data: ["<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-11")); ?>","<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-10")); ?>","<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-9")); ?>","<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-8")); ?>","<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-7")); ?>","<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-6")); ?>","<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-5")); ?>","<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-4")); ?>","<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-3")); ?>","<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-2")); ?>","<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("-1")); ?>","<?php echo impGetir($connectDb,$userr,aySayiGetir2("now")); ?>"],
          backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,0,0.4)",
          pointRadius: 4,
          pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
          //pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
          fill: false
        }]
        },
            options: {
                tooltips: { // this code
                    mode: 'label', // this code
                }, // this code
                scales: {
                  yAxes: [{
                    id: 'A',
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'left',
                  }, {
                    id: 'B',
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'right'
                  }]
                }
            }
        });
        </script>

    </div>
```

[Yeahha :) (Seem like this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7RXD.png)